# Intent to pick an installed application slow in my activity, why?

Tags: android

If you long press on your homescreen and pick to add an application shortcut, you will be greeted with a listview showing all of your instal applications.  I needed this same functionality in my application so I copied the intent from the launcher source:

```
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);            
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
        pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mainIntent);
        this.startActivityForResult(pickIntent, MoreIconsConstants.REQUEST_PICK_APPLICATION)
```

When this executes on the launcher it is pretty speedy.  When I execute this in my activity it takes maybe 15 seconds instead of 3.  It seems like the launcher must be caching this data for some amount of time?  Is there any way I can cache the data too?

Thanks!

Comment: If you've already taken that code from the launcher source, then you should be able to check relatively easily whether there's any caching going on! :)

Comment: I didn't see anything that jumped out at me for caching, but it doesn't change the fact that one is fast and one is slow :)

I also was not able to locate the code that goes on inside of that intent which pops up the listview.  Maybe the caching is going on in there but for some reason only works with the launcher.  Very frustrating.

Comment: how did u managed to select the app from the list of apps? i can't do it

Answer (score 2):

You can read all the apps that install by this code

```
final PackageManager pm = a.getPackageManager();

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    final List<ResolveInfo> apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    Collections.sort(apps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) 
    {
        ResolveInfo info = apps.get(i);
       //Intent to start the app
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,info.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        //Load app icon
        info.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm)
        //Load app label
        info.loadLabel(pm)
}
```

Check this example code
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/src/com/example/android/home/Home.html
search for loadApplications function

I had the same problem so what I did is to load the application by the code above in a thread.